# Is there a syntax that makes adding new components to a JPanel especially fast/efficient?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jpanel

I am trying to take the first steps towards writing an application that will move things to different places on the screen, remove some or add new ones, depending on what the user does. By now I successfully made a blank window, got it to go full screen and then added a label. I would like to try drawing some shapes next, But before I move on to that I will need to address an issue: For some reason it takes the computer several seconds to get the label displayed after it is added to my JPanel. But displaying some writing can't be that difficult of a task in and of itself, since the computer can do that without any noticeable delay if I tell a proper application to do it via Applescript. Thus I would think it reasonable to assume that the computer either takes a break here or that it does something extremely work intensive and inefficient to delay it this much. I already tried to update the screen using `revalidate()` but that appears to merely wipe the window clean until there is a reaction to the change (I tried what would happen if I used different colours on JFrame and JPanel and it seems that the JPanel goes invisible until drawing the label on it is done). This is definitely a good thing, since it will probably discourage the user from trying anything else until an action is completed. But I would still like it even better, if it did not take so long. I had a similar situation with how long it took to actually quit the app after the window was clicked away before - and managed to fix that by finding some different code to do the task - so I am hopeful that there is a better syntax here too. Thank you in advance for any tips you might have. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Painting
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dimension xyz = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        JFrame Canvas = new JFrame("Leinwand");
        Canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // damit das Fenster, auch wenn es leer ist, nicht ergraut
        Canvas.setSize(xyz.width,xyz.height);
        
        JPanel Fabric = new JPanel();
        Fabric.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Canvas.add(Fabric);
        Canvas.setVisible(true);
        
        JLabel Paint = new JLabel("Haaaaaaaaa...aaallo!");
        Fabric.add(Paint);
        Canvas.revalidate(); // hält im Endeffekt nur das Fenster leer, bis es wieder bereit ist - keine Beschleunigung erkennbar
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, you add the Swing components to the JPanel and the JPanel to the JFrame before you make the JFrame visible.

Comment: Sure - I can do that with the first components that the finished app should have - but what do I do about new stuff that gets added in later? (my endgoal is a tool that will draw something similar to a mindmap, so I can't know how many elements of what type I will need in the end before)

Comment: "similar to a mindmap" - Generally, I'd create one large drawing JPanel and draw.  I can't be more specific without knowing what "similar to a mindmap" actually means.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps of creating a prop[er Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn by example. I have never seen a text book or tutorial use incorrect variable names. *For some reason it takes the computer several seconds to get the label displayed after it is added to my JPanel.* - that is an issue with your code. The code you posted does not demonstrate this behaviour, so we can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: Just to get this straight: What places to use or not use capital letters at in names is a convention with the purpose of making more easily visible what kind of thing the names refer to, right? If so, then I'm sorry that I didn't change the writing before putting it here - As far as I know it doesn't make a difference for the performance of the app (Does it?) and when writing for myself I just felt good following the not programming related language convention of starting names (or for that matter statements) with capital letters - I should probably just adapt.

Comment: If you do not get to witness the behavior I described above, would it be possible that this problem is specific to Mac computers? I have only one real java application that I am aware of installed on my computer - and that one regularly makes my computer run so hot that I feel the need to send it to sleep so that it can cool down before I wake it up again to go on. If this happened on the computer which the app was written on, surely people would have worked to stop it from happening again, wouldn't they?

Comment: … or maybe things are slowed down by me not compiling the code separately before running it. In that case I would still like to find a solution, since if the slowed down version shows a delay then the sped up version might be more taxing on the computer.

Comment: I may have found a solution: Don't add new components to a JPanel - just put a public Array of things that should be drawn into a class that extends JPanel, declare a new Variable of that class and change the array as you go. Maybe this was too obvious for anyone to think that I had not considered it before (I did not try to paint labels yet) but at least with basic shapes it works instantly :)